# Mysql group by (custom number for result)

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table

```
Id Name   Id_collection  Price
1  good1  2              10
2  good2  1              101
3  good3  3              102
4  good4  2              10
5  good5  2              10
```

I need to Group By id_collection, but i need to show 2 rows (to be able to change this value via variable or ... Ex: to change to 3 or 4 )

```
not
1
2
3

Ex
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

or

```
Ex
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
```

so the result must be

```
Id Name   Id_collection  Price
1  good1  2              10
4  good4  2              10
2  good2  1              101
3  good3  3              102
```

I was thinking about procedure or loop, but i didn't that before, Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to group by adjacent values . . . in MySQL.  You can use variables to assign the group.  Alternatively, you can use this method to assign the group:  count the number of rows that have `id_collection` *different* from each row with a smaller id.

You don't specify how to calculate the other columns, but here is a guess:

```
select min(id) as id, min(name) as name, id_collection, avg(price) as price
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from t t2
              where t2.id_collection <> t.id_collection and
                    t2.id < t.id
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by id_collection, grp;
```

EDIT:

I just realized that you probably don't want to aggregate the results; you probably just want the first row.  For that, use variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@id = id_collection, @rn,
                        if(@id := id_collection, @rn + 1, @rn + 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @id = -1, @rn := 0) params
      order by id
     ) t
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: @Gordon_Linoff the first query works fine, the second does not (shows all rows), and for the first query, is that possible to show 3 or more number not only 2?

Comment: @AsylzatAzaev . . . There were a couple of typos.

Comment: @Gordon_Linoff your first example works great, but i can't figure out how to show 3 or 4 counts of grouped "id_collection", right now it is showing 2 counts, but that will be changed soon, and the second example showing all list of data with field "rn" which is always stays 1, Please HELP !!!

Answer (score 0):

I edited a little the answer which @Gordon_Linoff posted, and it works now, you just have to change rn <= 3 this number and will get the various results.

@Gordon_Linoff - Thank you, this really helped me

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@id = id_collection, @rn + 1,
                        if(@id := id_collection, 1, 0)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @id := -1, @rn := 0) params
      order by id_collection
     ) t
where rn <= 3;
```